# How to start last open activity after open some fixed activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

My requirement is when i minimize my app and maximize (open), one specific password enter screen must be display(Every time open when user open this app, and this is simple locale password). if user enter correct code then open the last activity where user left before minimize the app. And in my app there is lot of java class activity. in some solution stack overflow user suggest to use SharedPreferences for this. But i don't know how to apply that, so any idea?

Comment: hee every time you want to open an password activity and after a write pass is entered  you want to open a last closed activiy

Comment: please show the code in `when you minimize my app and maximize (open), one specific password enter screen must be display`

Comment: this may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969848/passcode-on-resume-from-background

Comment: @Shahbaaz90 thanks, is there any way without using SharedPreferences ?

Comment: @santoXme yes it should work like app locker is inbuilt with application

Comment: yup you can do it without shared preference you can use saved activity instance to  save the last opening state of app....for every time open an lockscreen activity you canuse a life cycle of activity ...when a activity go in background and again come some method called use that methods ....

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a boolean value to check weather the onStart is called for the first time. So if the onStart method is called again you can know that the activity is just minimized and then reopened. You can show the password prompt on that time.

```
private boolean isOnStartCalledFirstTime = false;
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(!isOnStartCalledFirstTime){
        isOnStartCalledFirstTime = true;
    }else {
        //Show password prompt
    }
}
```